# DHT22 reading weird values

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I just hooked up a DHT22 I had laying around in a parts drawer to test something and it is giving out some crazy wrong values, I am running the adafruit library's unified example and this is the output:

```
Resolution:   0.10%
------------------------------------
:   1
Unique ID:    -1
Max Value:    100.00%
Min Value:    0.00%
Resolution:   0.10%
------------------------------------
DHTxx Unified Sensor Example
------------------------------------
Temperature
Sensor:       DHT22
Driver Ver:   1
Unique ID:    -1
Max Value:    125.00 *C
Min Value:    -40.00 *C
Resolution:   0.10 *C
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
Humidity
Sensor:       DHT22
Driver Ver:   1
Unique ID:    -1
Max Value:    100.00%
Min Value:    0.00%
Resolution:   0.10%
------------------------------------
Temperature: 588.80 *C
Humidity: 998.40%
Temperature: 563.20 *C
Humidity: 1049.60%
Temperature: 563.20 *C
Humidity: 1024.00%
Temperature: 563.20 *C
Humidity: 1024.00%
Temperature: 563.20 *C
Humidity: 1024.00%
```

Had anyone seen behaviour like this before? of course my room isn't 600 *C or 1000% humidity XD

Its connected to an arduino UNO that I am pretty sure works fine.

Comment: Since the sensed  value exceed the max value, perhaps code error?

Comment: Arduino Mega:
"
Temperature: 716.80 *C
Humidity: 1024.00%
"
library fake :-(

Comment: Have you tried this with the standard libraries (AdaFruit_Sensor & DHT)?  Plus, it is helpful if you show the code you are using.